# Unable to run tests with JUnit5 Console Launcher

Tags: java, junit5

I am trying to run a simple test with the JUnit5 console launcher. I tried several options, but it does not work. Can somebody tell me what goes wrong?

`java -jar .\junit-platform-console-standalone-1.0.0-RC3.jar -c AFirstTest.class`

`java -jar .\junit-platform-console-standalone-1.0.0-RC3.jar -c AFirstTest`

gives me a warning

```
WARNUNG: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
```

I tried to run all tests in the directory, but this does not seem to find the test:

```
java -jar .\junit-platform-console-standalone-1.0.0-RC3.jar -d .
```

The result is this:

> .
> +-- JUnit Jupiter [OK]
> '-- JUnit Vintage [OK]
>
> Test run finished after 11 ms
> [         2 containers found      ]
> [         0 containers skipped    ]
> [         2 containers started    ]
> [         0 containers aborted    ]
> [         2 containers successful ]
> [         0 containers failed     ]
> [         0 tests found           ]
> [         0 tests skipped         ]
> [         0 tests started         ]
> [         0 tests aborted         ]
> [         0 tests successful      ]
> [         0 tests failed          ]

I am on Windows 10, and I was successful in running the tests from IntelliJ.

This is my test class:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
 
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
 
class AFirstTest {
 
    @Test
    void helloJUnit5() {
        assertEquals(2, 3 - 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: In which directory do you issue the command?
In which package does `AFirstTest` reside?

Comment: AFirstTest does not have a package. The console launcher jar and AFirstTest.class are in the same directory. Added the test class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to include the current directory in your classpath. Like:

```
java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.5.2.jar --class-path . -c AFirstTest
```

It should work without including it. I think. Would you mind raising an issue at https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues ?

Comment: I guess, the `-jar` option removes the `.` from the default classpath. So, you have to add it manually, as described above. This should work too:

`java -cp .;junit-platform-console-standalone-1.0.0-RC3.jar org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher  -c AFirstTest`

Comment: --class-path . does the trick! Allright so far, thanks. :) But why does it not discover the class with the directory option?

Comment: See my comment to this answer above. `-jar` passes the control of the classpath to the `jar`. Maybe, we should include `.` in its manifest.

Comment: java -jar .\junit-platform-console-standalone-1.0.0-RC3.jar --class-path . -d . still does not execute any tests.

Comment: True. Now that looks like bug. But, try `java -cp .;junit-platform-console-standalone-1.0.0-RC3.jar org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher  --scan-class-path`

Comment: This line and also the line in your first comment does not work for me. Java just prints out the available options. What works: `java -cp .\junit-platform-console-standalone-1.0.0-RC3.jar org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher --scan-class-path`. But this also does not execute my test

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152796/discussion-between-sormuras-and-anna).

Comment: I've run into the same issue, have you already found how to solve this problem？