# JUnit 5 Console does not find tests

Tags: unit-testing, ant, junit5

I am using JUnit5 Console in my Ant build script. However it does not find any tests in my project.

I've used the following command in Terminal:

```
-jar lib\junit-platform-console-standalone-1.1.0-RC1.jar --class-path bin --scan-class-path
```

which returns:

```
[36m.[0m
[36m+--[0m [36mJUnit Jupiter[0m [32m[OK][0m
[36m'--[0m [36mJUnit Vintage[0m [32m[OK][0m

Test run finished after 27 ms
[         2 containers found      ]
[         0 containers skipped    ]
[         2 containers started    ]
[         0 containers aborted    ]
[         2 containers successful ]
[         0 containers failed     ]
[         0 tests found           ]
[         0 tests skipped         ]
[         0 tests started         ]
[         0 tests aborted         ]
[         0 tests successful      ]
[         0 tests failed          ]
```

I get the same output for the Ant script:

```
<target name="test" depends="compile" description="Runs JUnit Tests">
    <java jar="lib\junit-platform-console-standalone-1.1.0-RC1.jar" fork="true">
        <arg value="d ."/>
        <arg value="-details verbose"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it: The Arguments have to be lines:

```
<target name="test" depends="test-javac" description="Runs JUnit Tests">
    <java jar="${junit.jar}" fork="true">

        <arg line="--class-path bin"/>
        <arg line="--scan-class-path"/>
        <arg line="--reports-dir reports"/>

        <!-- Available options: [ascii,unicode]-->
        <arg line="details-theme unicode"/>

        <!-- Available options: [none,flat,tree,verbose]-->
        <arg line="--details tree"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify where the launcher can find your compiled test classes. See https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher for details.

How are your test classes named? Are they stored by "javac" directly under "bin/"?

Maybe the answer and comments posted here [Unable to run tests with JUnit5 Console Launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869932/unable-to-run-tests-with-junit5-console-launcher) are helpful.

Comment: I checked for the compiled test classes, they were missing, which I've fixed now. However, I still get the same output as before.

Comment: The command line version (see above) gives the correct output. ant does not.