# unable to run junit5 tests from terminal using Junit5 Console Launcher

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, junit5

I'm performing unit tests for my spring boot application. The tests work fine and give the expected output while running from intellij. I'm trying to run the same tests from terminal using Junit5 Console Launcher. 
This is the command I've used :-

```
java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.6.0-RC1.jar --class-path . -c AdapterTest
```

I'm running the above command from `out/tests/package that contains the test class` folder.

I can see the required jars and dependencies in my external jars folder. But I'm getting the below error when I run it from terminal.

Entire stack trace :-

```
java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.6.0-RC1.jar --class-path . -c AdapterTest
Thanks for using JUnit! Support its development at https://junit.org/sponsoring
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:189)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:168)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
        at org.junit.platform.console.tasks.ConsoleTestExecutor.executeTests(ConsoleTestExecutor.java:66)
        at org.junit.platform.console.tasks.ConsoleTestExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ConsoleTestExecutor.java:58)
        at org.junit.platform.console.tasks.CustomContextClassLoaderExecutor.replaceThreadContextClassLoaderAndInvoke(CustomContextClassLoaderExecutor.java:41)
        at org.junit.platform.console.tasks.CustomContextClassLoaderExecutor.invoke(CustomContextClassLoaderExecutor.java:31)
        at org.junit.platform.console.tasks.ConsoleTestExecutor.execute(ConsoleTestExecutor.java:58)
        at org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher.executeTests(ConsoleLauncher.java:95)
        at org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher.execute(ConsoleLauncher.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher.execute(ConsoleLauncher.java:50)
        at org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher.execute(ConsoleLauncher.java:43)
        at org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher.main(ConsoleLauncher.java:37)
Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: ClassSelector [className = 'AdapterTest'] resolution failed
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.discovery.AbortOnFailureLauncherDiscoveryListener.selectorProcessed(AbortOnFailureLauncherDiscoveryListener.java:39)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolveCompletely(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:102)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.run(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:82)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.java:113)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolveSelectors(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:45)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:69)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: Could not load class with name: AdapterTest
        at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.lambda$getJavaClass$0(ClassSelector.java:75)
        at org.junit.platform.commons.function.Try$Failure.getOrThrow(Try.java:335)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.getJavaClass(ClassSelector.java:74)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.ClassSelectorResolver.resolve(ClassSelectorResolver.java:66)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.lambda$resolve$2(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:134)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1359)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
        at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:531)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:185)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:125)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolveCompletely(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:91)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AdapterTest
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:817)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.lambda$tryToLoadClass$9(ReflectionUtils.java:790)
        at org.junit.platform.commons.function.Try.lambda$call$0(Try.java:57)
        at org.junit.platform.commons.function.Try.of(Try.java:93)
        at org.junit.platform.commons.function.Try.call(Try.java:57)
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.tryToLoadClass(ReflectionUtils.java:753)
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.tryToLoadClass(ReflectionUtils.java:709)
        ... 32 more
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Tried everything mentioned here :- `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869932/unable-to-run-tests-with-junit5-console-launcher` but I'm still getting the above mentioned error. How do I run the tests from terminal?

Update :-
Tried running the command from out/tests  :-
Getting the following output :-

```
Thanks for using JUnit! Support its development at https://junit.org/sponsoring
╷
├─ JUnit Jupiter ✔
└─ JUnit Vintage ✔
Test run finished after 24 ms
[         2 containers found      ]
[         0 containers skipped    ]
[         2 containers started    ]
[         0 containers aborted    ]
[         2 containers successful ]
[         0 containers failed     ]
[         0 tests found           ]
[         0 tests skipped         ]
[         0 tests started         ]
[         0 tests aborted         ]
[         0 tests successful      ]
[         0 tests failed          ]
```

The tests are still not being run.

Comment: Have you tried running the comman from ˋout/testsˋ? Classpath components should point to the root of a compilation target dierectory.

Answer (score 0):

This is the command that works for me running it from a root folder in my project:

`java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.5.2.jar -classpath ./bin --scan-classpath`

`./bin` is the target folder containing my compiled classes.

I use this command to compile my tests from the terminal:

`javac -cp './src/:junit-jupiter-api-5.6.0-20200102.170103-207.jar' -d ./bin ./src/Assignment1Test.java`

`./src/Assignment1Test.java` is my Test class.

So, I start with this folder structure:

```
project
 |
 |-- junit-jupiter-api-5.6.0-20200102.170103-207.jar
 |-- junit-platform-console-standalone-1.5.2.jar
 |--bin
 |--src
     \ Assignment1.java
     \ Assignment1Test.java
```

And I end up with this:

```
project
 |
 |-- junit-jupiter-api-5.6.0-20200102.170103-207.jar
 |-- junit-platform-console-standalone-1.5.2.jar
 |--bin
     \ Assignment1.class
     \ Assignment1Test.class
 |--src
     \ Assignment1.java
     \ Assignment1Test.java
```

And then I run my tests

Comment: I tried what you said. It's not able to find other classes and libraries imported in my test class.

Comment: So, the problem occurs when you compile your test class?  You need to compile each file in your source folder including the class that you are testing, that should be compiled first. Depending on the test engine that you are using, you need to compile the Test Class with the jar of the engine. For Junit5 you got junit-jupiter-api, the one that I am using, and for back compatibility you got vintage. If you still having problems try to link a repo or something.